# HSSFWorkbook not upcast to Workbook

Tags: excel, upcasting

why not unable to compile :

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(in);
Workbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
```

the complier tell me "wb" should be HSSFWorkbook Object.

Comment: Workbook is only an interface. You can't create instances of an interface.

Comment: yes you can do that, it is the same as doing `List<T> = new ArrayList<T>`, List is an interface. And here, HSSFWorkbook implements Workbook

Comment: It should be possible and works for me, my suspition is you might not have the correct `Workbook` and `HSSFWorkbook` classes. 

Can you check your imports: these are the imports you should have:
`import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;` and `import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;`

Comment: Thks, I have done. But not this problem!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible as [HSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html) implements the [Workbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html) interface and it works for me, no compiling issue. My suspicion is you might not have the correct `Workbook` and `HSSFWorkbook` classes. Can you check your imports?

These are the imports you should have:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
```

Comment: thks, I have imported. I use  poi-3.17.jar. Did you use this version?

Comment: yes `compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.17'`